# how to exit from loop after a ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a table and I need to bulk updation. Before I need to check one column have no null value and the values are unique.So i loop the table.But how can i exit from the loop when same values appear in table?

i checked is there any null field.But after i cant exit from the loop where i checked unique values

when duplicate value occur i need to show in  countDuplicate  the row count of table.

```
 if (NullField==false)
    {

        $('#tblClassName tbody tr').each(function (i, item) 
        {
            countDuplicate = parseInt(countDuplicate + 1);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("IsAdmissionNumbervalid", "StudentDetailUpdation")",
                data: JSON.stringify({

                    AdmissionNo:             
$($(this).find("#txtAdmissionNumber")).val(),
                    FieldName: $("#ddlField option:selected").val(),
                    StudentID: $(this).find(".txtStudentID").html(),
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == "Failed") {
                        IsduplicateExist = true;                           

                        alert("Admission Number already exists");

                        return false;
                    }

                }

        })

            if (IsduplicateExist == true) {
                return false;
            }
            })
    }
    alert($('#tblClassName tbody tr').length)
    alert(countDuplicate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire `.each` loop is iterated before you get to process the responses. You need to sequalize the ajax calls if you want to control the loop based on their results.

Jquwry 1.5 ajax request returns a jqXHR object derived from the `Promis` interface.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise

So, you can sequalize your ajax calls with async/await and control the loop based on the responses. First, make your function an `async` function. The, use `await` to make the iterator wait until the response arrives.

```
       var res = await $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("IsAdmissionNumbervalid", "StudentDetailUpdation")",
            data: JSON.stringify({

                AdmissionNo:             
                   $($(this).find("#txtAdmissionNumber")).val(),
                   FieldName: $("#ddlField option:selected").val(),
                   StudentID: $(this).find(".txtStudentID").html(),
            }),

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"


      })

      if (res === "Failed")
         return false;    //exit the loop here
```

Additionally, you should use a try-catch block to catch any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable `IsduplicateExist` outside of the `.each()` function.

```js
if (NullField == false) {

  var IsduplicateExist; // Declare variable outside of loop
  $('#tblClassName tbody tr').each(function(i, item) {
    countDuplicate = parseInt(countDuplicate + 1);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "@Url.Action("
      IsAdmissionNumbervalid ", "
      StudentDetailUpdation ")",
      data: JSON.stringify({

        AdmissionNo: $($(this).find("#txtAdmissionNumber")).val(),
        FieldName: $("#ddlField option:selected").val(),
        StudentID: $(this).find(".txtStudentID").html(),
      }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == "Failed") {
          IsduplicateExist = true;

          alert("Admission Number already exists");

          return false;
        }

      }

    })

    if (IsduplicateExist == true) {
      return false;
    }
  })
}
alert($('#tblClassName tbody tr').length)
alert(countDuplicate)
```

Comment: its already declared outside the .each() function. when duplicate value  occur i need the rowcount in countDuplicate variable .Now its same as $('#tblClassName tbody tr').length

Comment: @Jasmine Hmm... Does Charlie H's solution work for you?